# "Manage Pages" not available as it is greyed out

Tags: looker-studio

The "Manage Pages" option is greyed out from the dropdown. When in view mode, I can see all of the pages and sections that I set up at the beginning, but now I am unable to go in and update this.

It was working fine yesterday and is only affecting one of my dashboards. This issue only occurs in my dashboards, which have all of their tabs as multi-layered sections (no independent dashboard tab is a separate page).

Is there a reason why the option is unavailable?

Answer (score 0):

Note that this is a [sporadic issue](https://support.google.com/datastudio/thread/166243494/manage-pages-menu-option-grey-out) and only affects certain dashboards (worked in the report and GIF below), though in any case, the method that I've been using as well as the recommended method on the [Add pages and report navigation](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6370267#manage-pages-pane&zippy=%2Cin-this-article:%7E:text=to%20your%20report.-,Manage%20report%20pages,-To%20manage%20the) support page is:

> ### Manage report pages
>
> To manage the pages you've added to your reports:
>
> 1. Edit your report.
> 2. In the upper left, click "Page X of Y."
>
> [image: manage_images]

Publicly editable [Google Data Studio](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/35d18670-7c5d-4bcf-8160-bd4cb0aea8a7) report (embedded Google Analytics data source based on the Tutorial Report) and a GIF to elaborate:

[image: gif]

Answer (score 0):

I found that adding a blank "helper" page on a fully independent tab (with no sections) provides a fix for this issue (just hide the blank page so it doesn't look out of place). I believe the "Manage Pages" option ends up getting disabled when the dashboard is built with multi-layered sections for each and every tab.